# Change Colour Of Text Mid-Way?

Tags: c#, syntax

So Basically, I Want to make just one word yellow colour, and the rest White, so what i did is:

```
Console.Write("Words ");
Console.ForegroudColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
Console.Write("Words ");
Console.ForegroudColor = ConsoleColor.White;
Console.Write("Words ");
```

is there a way for it to be done easier?

EX: (not working)

```
Console.Write("Words " + Console.ForegroudColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow; + "Words");
```

Comment: I believe ANSI color codes will work. It might depend on the console.

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
YOU should __always__ TAG your questions correctly so one can see it on the questions page!

Comment: Well as you got a working example you can write a function that can read the 'small languag' you wish..

Comment: https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/using-ansi-color-codes-in-net-console-apps/ This shows how to do it via ANSI color codes and some P/Invoke into the Windows API to enable it - but you probably shouldn't do it ;)

Comment: Also, see here for the escape codes that become available if you enable it as mentioned in my previous comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences

Comment: @MatthewWatson Thanks! I've learned something new today :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not something built in - however I have an open source project called [ExtendedConsole](https://github.com/Peled-Zohar/ExtendedConsole) on GitHub that does exactly that, using simple xml-based markup.

[The documentation is hosted on GitHub pages](https://peled-zohar.github.io/ExtendedConsole/) and you can download it as a [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ExtendedConsole).

and use it like this:

```
exConsole.Write("Somw words here <c f='yellow'>This is yellow!</c> some more words here");
```

It also contains many other things that can make your life easier when writing console applications such as menus and read methods.